# Cannot connect with server "http.send" issue

Tags: vba

When I run this code I get a Run Time error saying that 'a connection with the server could not be established'   Is this a problem with my settings in excel?  Or maybe a problem with the security features on my computer? When I type the url into my browser it works. I want the csv to download and pop out in the msgbox.  Once I can do that I will then try to get the csv info into my spreadsheet, but Im stuck even getting the info to download.  Also, when I debug, the issue seems to be with the 'http.send' line. 
**note, a similar question was asked but I tried to use those responses and none of them fixed mine, so I think I need a new fix**

```
Sub stocks()


Dim W As Worksheet: Set W = ActiveSheet

Dim Last As Integer: Last = W.Range("a1000").End(xlUp).Row

If Last = 1 Then Exit Sub
Dim Symbols As String
Dim i As Integer

For i = 2 To Last
    Symbols = Symbols & W.Range("A" & i).Value & "+"


Next i

Symbols = Left(Symbols, Len(Symbols) - 1)


Dim URL As String: URL = "http://download.finance.yahoo.com/d/quotes.csv?s=" & Symbols & "&f=snl1hg"

Dim http As New WinHttpRequest
http.Open "Get", URL, False
http.Send

MsgBox http.ResponseText



End Sub
```

Comment: What's the response code?

Comment: Run-Time Error '-2147012867 (80072efd)': A connection with the server could not be established @MacroMan

Comment: I meant the server response code - you can use XMLHTTP instead though

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use XMLHTTP instead:

```
Dim http As Object
Set http = CreateObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP")
http.Open "Get", URL, False
http.Send
```